# Non-numeric argument to binary operator R NLS package

Tags: r

I am using the nls package in R to perform a nonlinear fit. I have specified my independent variable as follows:

```
t <- seq(1,7)
```

and my dependent variables as P <- c(0.0246, 0.2735, 0.5697, 0.6715, 0.8655, 0.9614, 1)

I then have tried:

`m <- nls(P ~ 1 / (c + q*exp(-b*t))^(1/v))`,

but every time I get:

> "Error in c + q * exp(-b * t) : non-numeric argument to binary
>   operator"

Every one of my variables is numeric. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Provide `c`, `q`, `b`, and `v` as well?

Comment: ... as starting values.

Comment: Try adding more `()` : `m <- nls(P ~ (1 / (c + q*exp(-b*t))^(1/v)))`

Comment: You also get an warning with a recommendation: *Consider specifying 'start' or using a selfStart model*. If you specify `start` `nls` is able to identify better what are parameters and interpret your formula correctly.

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one problem in your script. The main issue is that you should never use names which are used by R: `t` is the matrix transpose, `c` is a common method to create vectors, and `q` is the quit instruction. `nls()` will not try to fit them, as they are already defined. I recommend using more meaningful and less dangerous variables such as `Coef1`, `Coef2`, …

The second problem is that you are trying to fit a model with 4 variables to a dataset with 7 data... This may yield singularities and other problems.

For the sake of the argument, I have reduced your model to three variables, and changed some names:

```
Time <- seq(1,7)
Prob <- c(0.0246, 0.2735, 0.5697, 0.6715, 0.8655, 0.9614, 1)
plot(Time, Prob)
```

[image]

And now we perform the nls() fit:

```
Fit <- nls(Prob ~ 1 / (Coef1 + Coef2 * exp(-Coef3 * Time))) 
X   <- data.frame(Time = seq(0, 7, length.out = 100))
Y   <- predict(object = Fit, newdata = X)
lines(X$Time, Y)
```

[image]

And a summary of the results:

```
summary(Fit)           
# Formula: Prob ~ 1/(Coef1 + Coef2 * exp(-Coef3 * Time))
# 
# Parameters:
# Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# Coef1  1.00778    0.06113  16.487 7.92e-05 ***
# Coef2 23.43349   14.42378   1.625   0.1796    
# Coef3  1.04899    0.21892   4.792   0.0087 ** 
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.06644 on 4 degrees of freedom
# 
# Number of iterations to convergence: 12 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.04e-06
```

I know it is not exactly what you wanted, but I hope it helps.